# Destructuring a list with equations in maxima

Tags: variables, maxima

Say that I have the following list of equations:

`list: [x=1, y=2, z=3];`

I use this pattern often to have multiple return values from a function. Kind of of like how you would use an object, in for example, javascript. However, in javascript, I can do things like this. Say that `myFunction()` returns the object `{x:1, y:2, z:3}`, then I can destructure it with this syntax:

```
let {x,y,z} = myFunction();
```

And now `x,y,z` are assigned the values `1,2,3` in the current scope.

Is there anything like this in maxima? Now I use this:

```
x: subst(list, x); 
y: subst(list, y);
z: subst(list, z);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this. Let `l` be a list of equations of the form `somesymbol = somevalue`. I think all you need is:

```
map (lhs, l) :: map (rhs, l);
```

Here `map(lhs, l)` yields the list of symbols, and `map(rhs, l)` yields the list of values. The operator `::` means evaluate the left-hand side and assign the right-hand side to it. When the left-hand side is a list, then Maxima assigns each value on the right-hand side to the corresponding element on the left.

E.g.:

```
(%i1) l : [a = 12, b = 34, d = 56] $
(%i2) map (lhs, l) :: map (rhs, l);
(%o2)                            [12, 34, 56]
(%i3) values;
(%o3)                            [l, a, b, d]
(%i4) a;
(%o4)                                 12
(%i5) b;
(%o5)                                 34
(%i6) d;
(%o6)                                 56
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably achieve it and write a function that could be called as `f(['x, 'y, 'z], list)`; but you will have to be able to make some assignments between symbols and values. This could be done by writing a tiny *ad hoc* Lisp function being:

```
(defun $assign (symb val) (set symb val))
```

You can see how it works (as a first test) by first typing (form within Maxima):

```
:lisp (defun $assign (symb val) (set symb val))
```

Then, use it as: `assign('x, 42)` which should assign the value `42` to the *Maxima* variable `x`.

If you want to go with that idea, you should write a tiny Lisp file in your `~/.maxima` directory (this is a directory where you can put your most used functions); call it for instance `myfuncs.lisp` and put the function above (without the `:lisp` prefix); then edit (in the very same directory) your `maxima-init.mac` file, which is read at startup and add the two following things:

- add a line containing `load("myfuncs.lisp");` before the following part;
- define your own Maxima function (in plain Maxima syntax with no need to care about Lisp). Your function should contain some kind of loop for performing all assignments; now you could use the `assign(symbol, value)` function for each variable.

Your function could be something like:

```
f(vars, l) := for i:1 thru length(l) do assign(vars[i], l[i]) $
```

which merely assign each value from the second argument to the corresponding symbol in the first argument.

Thus, `f(['x, 'y], [1, 2])` will perform the expected assigments; of course you can start from that for doing more precisely what you need.

Comment: Interesting technique :)  Thanks for pointing out to me how to use lisp code in maxima.